# Preference order in Spring Bean container

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need to know what is the preference order when both setter and constructor injection is applied to a same class.

I wrote a demo code and found that it gives preference to setter injection.

```
<bean id="wolf" class="com.sac.DI.Wolf" />
<bean id="lion" class="com.sac.DI.Lion" />
<bean id="zoo" class="com.sac.DI.Zoo">
    <constructor-arg ref="lion" />
    <property name="wild" ref="wolf" />
</bean>
```

Zoo bean looks like below.

```
package com.sac.DI;

public class Zoo {

    private WildAnimal wild;

    public Zoo(WildAnimal animal) {
        this.wild = animal;
    }

    public void setWild(WildAnimal wild) {
        this.wild = wild;
    }

    public void testSound() {
        System.out.println(wild.sound());
    }
}
```

So my Queries are :

1. Is it always a setter Injection that is given preference or there is some property that defines it.
2. Why Setter injection is given preference over constructor injection

Comment: Why. Because first an object is contructed with the reference to `lion` then the setter is called overwriting the previously set `lion` to `wolf`.. It has nothing to do with preferences or favoring one over the other, it is the way you have configured things.

Comment: No, if i put constructor injection first it again gives preference to setter injection

Comment: Again that is how you have configured things (it has nothing to do with the ordering and never will have anything to do with the ordering) and how java works... How would you call a setter on a non constructed object...

Answer (score 0):

Using annotations instead xml configuration you can see clearer what [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) says:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public WildAnimal wolf(){
        return new Wolf();
    }

    @Bean
    public WildAnimal lion(){
        return new Lion();
    }

    @Bean
    public Zoo zoo(){
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo(lion());
        zoo.setWild(wolf());
        return zoo;
    }
}
```

First, you create an object using constructor injection, then you overwrite the property using setter injection.

Hope it helps.